# What is the meaning of these Lido abbreviations?

Tags: flight-planning, fuel, time

Can someone help with the abbreviations and meaning from Lido flight planning:

- RCONT 5 MIN
- HLDDST
- ADDT

For each of these abbreviations, the flight plan has fuel and time:

[image: Lido Flight Plan]

I placed a red rectangle around the abbreviations; I Hold Distance is ok, however I still o not understand RCONT

Comment: Likely planning factors like "hold distance" and "Additional distance". How much fuel for each abbreviation?

Answer (score 1):

RCONT is route reserve / contingency fuel:

[SKYbrary Fuel - Flight Planning Definitions](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Fuel_-_Flight_Planning_Definitions#Contingency_Fuel_.2F_Route_Reserve)

> Contingency fuel is carried to account for additional enroute fuel consumption caused by wind, routing changes or ATM: ATM/CNS restrictions. According to ICAO Annex 6, the recommended minimum contingency fuel is the greater of 5% of the trip fuel or 5 minutes holding consumption at 1500' above destination airfield elevation computed based on calculated arrival weight.

In this case the 5 minute holding consumption is greater than the 5% of trip fuel, so it is the one considered in calculation.

Comment: Do you know why it says **LFPG** (Paris Charles de Gaulles) behind the **RCONT** line? I understand the **EHRD** (Rotterdam The Hague) behind the **ALTN**, that is just the primary alternate, but why list Paris behind contingency when flying from Lisbon to Amsterdam?

Comment: @Bianfable this would be guessing, but I suspect RCONT might be specified in this case due to weather forecast for ETA in DST and/or ALTN airports being marginal. In this case a secondary alternate would have to be designated, LFPG being the secondary. Enroute alternate would not apply for tap672 as it is not an ETOPS flight not by a long shot ;)

Comment: It is also possible that there was a traffic situation in LFPG area, but this is even more speculative...